# Blur image in specified area at imageview in android?

Tags: android

[image]I have imageview in my application, I want to make a Blur effect on imageview image at specified area. For example, I have imageview with image 480 * 400, I want to make blur effect at top or middle or bottom of the image. Is it possible or not? If it is possible please let me know and guide me how to do that?

Comment: May I know you want to add some effect on photos ? Like blur other places and make focus on things you want ? Is it ?

Comment: Not like that, not focus in particular thing, I want the blur effect on photo where ever I need, it may be bottom on the image or top of the image or middle of the image. Also I don't want in full image Blur, I want the Blur effect on Image at specified area.

Comment: Let me clear ! You want to do like that your example photo ? Blur in the bottom and show text ?

Comment: Yes, but in this they are using two imageview for do this. I want to make the blur effect image itself

Answer (score 0):

You can use RenderScript for quality gaussian blur. See [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/08/renderscript-intrinsics.html).

I can suggest the following strategy:

In order to apply it to image I would make a copy of original image, apply gaussian blur to this copy, and then cut a necessary polygon from the blurred image. After that draw the blurred polygon on top of the source image.